# Chrome SE topbar broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I'm not sure where to post this, but for the last two days the top-bar interaction at RPG.SE.com has been broken under Chrome. I had a notice button that I couldn't click on and the popdown arrow "V" didn't work. Also the Winter Blast stopped appearing under chrome.

[image: chrome]

It all works properly under Firefox.

[image: firefox]

Comment: I don't have that bug with Chrome. Are you logged in in Chrome?

Comment: It is now working correctly again.

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue, Chrome is known for its very aggressive caching algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I can't repro this, and it seems you can't any longer either.  It's likely a bad cache in play as Maurycy said...since it's resolved I'm closing this out.  If you can repro please reply here and we'll dig deeper.